# Excel vba to copy and paste a cells from different worksheets to new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

i need a macro to copy and paste a certain cells(b5:d10) from multiple worksheets and paste it into a new single worksheet. just i want to collide the contents .thanks in advance

```
sub copyrange()
range("b5:d10).copy
range("e1").select
activesheet.paste
application.cutcopymode=false
endsub
```

my code doesnot copy all the worksheets data. kindly help me to copy and paste it

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copyrange()
    Dim rngTarget As Range, wksTemp As Worksheet

    Set rngTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:C7")

    For Each wksTemp In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        rngTarget.Value = wksTemp.Range("B5:D10").Value
        Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(6)
    Next wksTemp
End Sub
```

Comment: this code is not working . thus it moves my content to a temporary loaction dude. i need to copy and paste it into a new worksheet from various worksheets